# Zero Values in Multi-Linear Regression Model

Tags: python, linear-regression

I'm building a multi-linear regression model with data by day where the independent variables are sometimes zero as shown below (each line represents a different day of the year):

| X1 | X2 | X3 | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 8 | 3 | 9 |
| 3 | 2 | 8 | 7 |
| 0 | 4 | 1 | 4 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | 6 |
| 9 | 9 | 0 | 12 |

Should the zeros be left in the regression model or should they be removed?

Comment: it depends on the meaning the range values and the scale of your dependent variables. For example, if `x1` is income - expenses, it is meaningful to consider zero values.

Comment: @MiguelTrejo X1 is expenses and Y is sales. So where X1 is zero it means that on that day there haven't been any expenses through X1 although there might have been through X2, X3 etc.